# PHP- Sending a daily email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am making a website that sends people who sign up for it an email every day in the morning. The problem I have run into is that I don't know how to send an email at the same time everyday in php. I do know how to send an email, all I need to know how to send one daily.

Comment: I don’t think that PHP is really meant to run scheduled tasks like that. Can you run a cron job on your server instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup a CronJob for that. Only make the PHP that sends the email you want and prepare a CronJob in your server that executes every day (you can specify the time of the day).

I would use [Tectite Formmail](http://www.tectite.com)

If you have, for example, GoDaddy hosting, you can follow this instructions: [CronJob GoDaddy](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3548/accessing-your-cron-job-manager-with-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to run cron, it will already be installed and configured on your server.

To build-up your list, set up a form that subscribes people to your list, adding them to a database - don't forget to use double-opt-in.

Then write a PHP script that generates a message for everyone on your list and sends it to them - there is [a code example that does exactly this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) bundled with PHPMailer. To let cron know how to run the script, make this the first line of the file (*before* `<?php`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Finally, get cron to run it - this is trivially simple - just symlink it into `/etc/cron.daily/` and it will get run when cron runs each day. Look in `/etc/crontab` to see when this is, and alter it if you like. For example:

```
ln -s /path/to/my/script /etc/cron.daily/myscript
```